# Get Row of DataGrid in User Control Page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, datagridview, datagrid, visual-studio-2003

My Question is related to access the rows in one page and putting conditions in another page.

I need to check whether a datagrid has row in it or not. DataGrid is in .aspx page. Based on this checking i need to write a condition in .ascx page.

**the .ascx on which condition is checked is linked to .aspx page.** Meaning that UserControl1.ascx is Register with Default.aspx page

I am using VS 2003

Please advice

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an flag in `Session`? For instance, when you render the grid over aspx, get the number of rows, `MyDataTable.Rows.Count` and add into the session, like `Session["MyDataTable.Rows.Count"] = MyDataTable.Rows.Count`; from the ascx, check the value in session, and let your app make a decision based upon that value.

Comment: where should i write DataGrid.Rows.count? In some event like item command or in databind method?